# Question about Taylor series vs Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis

I'm starting to study Taylor series for the first time seriously, I kind of ignored them when I first took calculus but now that I'm doing Real Analysis I've been trying to really understand them.

One thing I was curious about is the difference between Fourier and Taylor series (other than that the basis functions are different). What I mean is, if a function meets the condition for a fourier series, then theoretically by taking enough terms, you could re-create the function over the whole real number line just using the series right?

It seems like with taylor polynomials, the idea is that because they are defined in neighborhoods about some point, say $c$, then taking more terms of the series only means that you are re-creating the function in some neighborhood about $c$. But if I took enough terms could I re-create the original function over the whole number line?

Thanks

Comment: Fourier series are usually defined for a closed interval or for periodic functions, but still you're right in a certain sense that Fourier series carry more global information.

Comment: Unless you look at the complex numbers, then the Fourier series is just a tiny part of a taylor series, at the boundary :) @GrumpyParsnip

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fourier series are designed for periodic functions. When you calculate the Fourier series of a function, you assume that this function is periodic. So, when you have a Fouries series that represents a function on the period interval (oftentimes that's $[0,2\pi]$), the Fourier series represents that function on the whole real line.

With Taylor series, it's different. You don't assume that the given function is periodic. You "hope" to express the function in the neighborhood of a given point by its Taylor series centered at that point. An important value for a Taylor series is its "radius of convergence" which says on what part of the real line the Taylor series makes sense. It's not necessarily true that a function defined on all - or most - of $\mathbb R$ can be expressed by its Taylor series centered at a specific point. Consider for example
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j.
$$
$f$ is defined on $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\},$ and the r.h.s is its Taylor series centered at $0.$ The Taylor series converges for $|x| < 1,$ which doesn't coincide with the domain of definition of $f.$

The behavior of Taylor series becomes much more understandable if you move from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C.$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that last statement and explain? Taking Calculus BC now, and I have been working with taylor series outside of class for weeks trying to understand them.

Comment: @louiemcconnell Consider, for example, the function $g(x) = 1/(x^2+1).$ This function behaves rather nicely on the real axis. It's bounded, it's $C^\infty,$ it tends to $0$ as $|x|$ tends to $0.$ Its Taylor series centered at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^n.$ This series converges only for $|x| < 1,$ without obvious reason! There is no singularity as in the example from my answer. However, if you move from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C,$ you find that $g(x) = 1/((x+i)(x-i))$ has singularities at $\pm i.$ Those restrict the radius of convergence of the Taylor series centered at $0$.

Comment: @louiemcconnell [continued] For more details, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Radius_of_convergence_in_complex_analysis).